# How to Export an existing 2-year-old logs (entire tables) in log analytics to a storage account

Tags: export, azure-log-analytics-workspace

How to Export an existing 2-year-old logs in log analytics to a storage account

Data export option exports only new ingesting logs not the existing logs. There are 8 tables around 8TB of data to be exported and need to import to a new log analytics workspace.

Answer (score 0):

> How to Export an existing 2-year-old logs (entire tables) in log analytics to a storage account

There is other export option with logic app to export the data. You can query data from a Log Analytics workspace in Azure Monitor and send it to Azure Storage with the help of logic app.

Check this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/logs-export-logic-app) to understand more about fetching data from Log Analytics workspace to Azure storage using Logic App

> This procedure uses the **Azure Monitor Logs connector**, which lets you run a log query from a logic app and use its output in other actions in the workflow. The **Azure Blob Storage connector** is used in this procedure to send the query output to storage.[image]